# spring.cloud.discovery.enabled seems not working since Spring Cloud Edgware.RC1

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

This property still works until Edgware.M1 but broken in Edgware.RC1. I dig into the issues related to spring-cloud-commons and found some issue like

> - [Make use of `@EnableDiscoveryClient` optional](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/218)
> - [Remove the need for @EnableDiscoveryClient](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/pull/245)

So that means "DiscoveryClient" utilize spring-boot auto-configuration feature right now? But what is the proper way to disable the "DiscoveryClient" feature from command line like before

```
--spring.cloud.discovery.enabled = false
```

Comment: Seems like that should still work.  I suggest you try is with the latest Edgware release SR2.

Comment: @RyanBaxter [A simple demonstration](https://github.com/reliveyy/poc-edgware-sr2-discovery-enabled-broken) showing this property still not working in SR2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Edgware we decided to separate the concept of service discovery and a discovery client, the two are independent.  For example

- You might have a service the needs to use a discovery client to make requests to other services but does not want to register itself in the discovery service
- You might have a service that wants to be discoverable by other services but does not need a discovery client.

You can disable the auto registration by setting `spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled: false` in addition to setting `spring.cloud.discovery.enabled: false` to disable both pieces of functionality.